# Flutter project AndroidManifest.xml file shows compilation errors but app run on android

Tags: android, flutter

I started working on a flutter project and everything is working fine. My app compiles and runs on android. However, I opened up this file and noticed that there were a lot of compilation errors. I want to know why this is and how I can fix it. I have included the file and errors listed below. I am working in android studio.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.flutter_course">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="flutter_course"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

IDE error messages

```
Error:(9, 26) Unresolved package 'flutter'
Error:(9, 34) Unresolved package 'app'
Error:(9, 38) Unresolved class 'FlutterApplication'
Error:(11, 23) Cannot resolve symbol '@mipmap/ic_launcher'
Error:(17, 28) Unresolved class 'MainActivity'
Error:(19, 28) Cannot resolve symbol '@style/LaunchTheme'
Error:(29, 33) Cannot resolve symbol '@style/NormalTheme'
Error:(38, 33) Cannot resolve symbol '@drawable/launch_background'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the errors. The app should work fine.

I think the errors shows because whatever parses or formats the code can't read XML well. It might go away if you install an XML formatter extension.